# Python import urllib.request and .error why not only import urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-3.4

Why does this not works (in Python 3.4.1)

```
import urllib
```

but this works

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
```

I think when I import `urllib` it should import also .request and .error but thats not the case. Why?

Comment: Please paste the stacktrace. I think it is a bug.

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy: why do you think this is a bug? I don't think it is..

Comment: Oops. I didn't read the last paragraph.You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Importing a module/package does not automatically import sub-module/sub-packages. (unless the imported module itself explicitly do it)